# c# Entry point was not found

Tags: c#, winforms, syncfusion

I am using the syncfusion grid control. 
Converting the grid to word gives me a Entry point was not found exception.

Here's the code I have so far

```
 private void cmdSaveData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            ////CEC: this btn is labeled to Define a new group
            //cmdDefineGroup_Click(sender, e);
        GridWordConverter converter = new GridWordConverter(true, true);
        converter.DrawHeader += new GridWordConverterBase.DrawDocHeaderFooterEventHandler(converter_DrawHeader);
        converter.DrawFooter += new GridWordConverterBase.DrawDocHeaderFooterEventHandler(converter_DrawFooter);
        converter.GridToWord("Sample.doc", theGrid);
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Sample.doc");
    }

    void converter_DrawFooter(object sender, DocHeaderFooterEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Footer.AddParagraph().AppendText("Copyright 2001-2008");
    }

    void converter_DrawHeader(object sender, DocHeaderFooterEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Header.AddParagraph().AppendText("Syncfusion Inc.");
    }
```

Here's the stack trace

```
   at Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.Grid.IGridVolatileData.get_HasColCount()
   at Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.Grid.GridModel.get_ColCount()
   at Syncfusion.GridHelperClasses.GridWordConverter.GridToWord(String filename, GridControlBase grid)
   at FP.frmData.cmdSaveData_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\FP\frmData.cs:line 365
```

[image]

Comment: Please show the complete exception, not *just* the stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just posting the stack trace, I don't see any exception in the post.

Obviously the "Entry Point was not found" might be referencing to your application startup, do you have your `Main()` defined in your project ?

**UPDATE**:
Now I can see the stack trace, it seem like you are missing some dependent assemblies , and what are the word engines you use ?

Comment: He added information about the exception. (So maybe you should refresh and wait for it to load?) He does have a Main method (in the running application), because it only throws the exception when he clicks the button.

Comment: @Turbot: I have like 6projects in the solution. This word converter  is not the first step in the program. Afterthe grid loads and shows, One of the menu buttonclick, is supposed to export he grid to word

Comment: Thanks, I was using a .Net 2.0 version of the word converted reference instead of 4.0